# And I thought I understood scope

Tags: javascript

Can someone please tell me why the last logging of 'x' equals 0 and not 1. I thought because it's declared outside of a function it has global scope and then in the function it's value is set to 1 and that value would remain as it's a global? I know the first 'x' value inside the function is a global as any variable declared without the var keyword becomes a property of the window object. Many thanks

```
var x = 0; //global variable

function y(){
  x = 1;
  log("1. %n ", x);//1. 1

  var x = 2;
  log("2. %n ", x);//2. 2
}

y();
log("3. %n ", x);//3. 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `var` statement is subject of *hoisting*, when your code is evaluated it actually looks like this:

```
var x = 0; //global variable
function y(){
  var x; // local!!

  x = 1;
  log("1. %n ", x);//1. 1

  x = 2;
  log("2. %n ", x);//2. 2
}

y();
log("3. %n ", x);//3. 0
```

Just before `y` is executed, a new execution context is setup, and the [Variable Instantiation](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.1.3) process takes place *before* the function is executed.

That's one of the reasons about why JSLint recommends only one var statement per function, to resemble what is actually happening.

Answer (score 5):

The variable `x` inside the function is created immediately when the function is executed and not just when the line with the [variable statement](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-12.2) is reached:

> If the variable statement occurs inside a *FunctionDeclaration*, the variables are defined with function-local scope in that function […]. Variables are created when the execution scope is entered. […] Variables are initialised to **undefined** when created. […]

You can see that `x` is initially `undefined` when adding a `log` call in front of the first assignment:

```
function y(){
  log("0. " + x);//0. undefined
  x = 1;
  log("1. " + x);//1. 1
  var x = 2;
  log("2. " + x);//2. 2
}
```

That means both assignments inside the function refer to `x` in the function-local scope and not to `x` in the global scope.

Comment: +1 yes, and see CMS's answer also because it uses the missing word "hoisting".

Comment: +1 Thanks man. Just when I think I know what's going on with JavaScript something else stumps me. Thanks for a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

I *think*, but cannot confirm via the ecmascript spec, that the "var x = 2" line is scanned at function definition time, and the local scope of "x" applies for the entire function, not just after the "var x" line's position in the function.

Here's a simpler test case (tested via [jsdb](http://www.jsdb.org)):

```
js>x = 0;
0
js>function foo(k) { x=k; }
js>function bar(k) { var x=k; }
js>function baz(k) { x=k; var x=2; }
js>foo(1)
js>x
1
js>bar(2)
js>x
1
js>baz(3)
js>x
1
```

You'll note that the only function here that affects the global "x" is `foo()`. The function `bar()` obviously affects only a local x. But the function `baz()` affects only the local x as well. You would think that the assignment `x=k;` would affect the global x, since it happens "before" the next statement `var x = 2;` which is clearly affecting a local variable x. But I'm pretty sure that if you do `var x` in a function, the interpreter sees it and applies it to *all* uses of x in that scope. Same situation as yours.